# Why do \setcounter and \addtocounter commands have global effect, while \setlength and \addtolength commands obey the normal scoping rules?

Tags: counters, lengths, grouping

> The `\setcounter` and `\addtocounter` commands have global effect,
>   while the `\setlength` and `\addtolength` commands obey the normal
>   scoping rules.

Why were they designed like this? Why are `\setcounter` and `\addtocounter` not defined to obey normal scoping rules?

Answer (score 13):

That is by design and coded accordantly in the LaTeX core source code. Counters in LaTeX usually count things which are independent from the local group. For example `figure` captions are enclosed in the group added by the `figure` environment and any change to the `figure` counter used by the caption would be lost afterwards. This would render the counter mostly useless.

If you want to set a counter locally use `\c@<counter name>=value`. To add something to it use `\advance\c@<counter name> by value`. To build the counter macro you can use `\csname name\endcsname` or (mis-)use `\value{name}` which also works on the left hand side of an assignment.

You can also define an own counter using the TeX macro `\newcount\yourcounter` and then use `\yourcounter=<value>` etc. However, you then need to define the `\theyourcounter` macro yourself if you need it and can't use the normal counter formating macros like `\arabic{..}` or `\roman{..}` with it.

Comment: I would say you can do `\newcount\mycount`, and only talk about using counters if they are defined with the appropriate LaTeX2e naming convention (`\c@...`).

Comment: @Joseph: Yeah, the one is a LaTeX counter and the other one a TeX count(er). You have to keep them separated.

Comment: With `\newcount\xyz`, `\arabic{xyz}` or `\alph{xyz}` don't work, as you say. But `\@arabic\xyz` or `\@alph\xyz` do.