# global confusion

Tags: tex-core, grouping

Simply put, when should I care if something is global or not? What does this really mean?

If my package, for example, provides

```
\newcommand*{\setfooter}[1]{\def\mypackage@footer{#1}}
```

And I later use `\mypackage@footer` inside the package, is it correct that i used `\def` and not `\gdef`?

To append to `\maketitle`, why do i use `\gappto{\maketitle}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}` (`\gappto` is from `etoolbox`, equivalent to `\g@addto@macro`) rather than simply `\appto`, when both seem to work? (from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61492/8289))

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you issue

```
\setfooter{foo}
```

at the top level, that is not inside a group or an environment (and `document` doesn't count as environment in this respect), there's no difference.

However, an input such as

```
{\setfooter{foo}}
```

would result in `\mypackage@footer` *not* be defined any more as soon as the closing brace is scanned.

If you suspect that users of your package may issue `\setfooter` in a group, then use `\gdef`.

Why using `\gappto` and not `\appto`? That's the same reasoning. I'd recommend to use "global" in both cases, so you won't incur in obscure malfunctions.

In the answer you link, Werner used `\g@addto@macro` because the LaTeX kernel doesn't provide a "local" equivalent.

Comment: So it would make sense to "default" to global definitions unless I have a reason not to?

Comment: @Mk12 No: in general local definitions should be preferred; it depends on *what* you're defining: something that should remain the same throughout the document is a candidate to be defined globally or at the top level (and usually in the preamble). Something that *must* transcend the group in which it possibly appears also should be "globally defined".

Comment: With my footer example, that should remain the same throughout the document, but it also should be defined in the preamble at top level—to me it really doesn't make sense to use it any other way.

Answer (score 15):

Macro definitions are considered as the "replacement text" for the given "macro and argument". So, with a definition like

```
\newcommand*{\setfooter}[1]{\def\mypackage@footer{#1}}
```

the use of `\setfooter` in your code is replaced with `\def\mypackage@footer{#1}`. If `\setfooter` is [not] inside a group, then `\def\mypackage@footer{#1}` will also [not] be inside that group. So, if the usage the macro and its eventual replacement is not required globally (outside the group), you don't need to declare it globally (with a `\gdef` or `\xdef`).

Here's a small example highlighting the above discussion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{\def\myothermacro{#1}}
\newcommand{\mygmacro}[1]{\gdef\myothergmacro{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begingroup% Start a group
\mymacro{test1}% Local definition of \myothermacro as test1
\endgroup% End a group
\show\myothermacro% \myothermacro is undefined
\mymacro{test1}% Local definition of \myothermacro as test1
\show\myothermacro% \myothermacro is defined as test1
\myothermacro% test1

\begingroup% Start a group
\mygmacro{test2}% Global definition of \myothergmacro as test2
\endgroup% End a group
\show\myothergmacro% \myothergmacro is defined as test2
\mygmacro{test2}% Global definition of \myothergmacro as test2
\show\myothergmacro% \myothergmacro is defined as test2
\myothergmacro% test2
\end{document}​
```

which yields the `.log` output of

```
> \myothermacro=undefined.
l.8 \show\myothermacro


> \myothermacro=macro:
->test1.
l.10 \show\myothermacro


> \myothergmacro=macro:
->test2.
l.16 \show\myothergmacro


> \myothergmacro=macro:
->test2.
l.18 \show\myothergmacro
```

Note that `\myothermacro` is undefined on `l.8`, since its definition was local on `l.6` (inside a group). `\myothergmacro`, however, is defined as `test2` on `l.16`, since it was globally defined (or `\gdef`-ed) on `l.14`.

It is also possible to precede the required global definition with `\global`, if its needed. So, in the above example, using

```
\global\mymacro{test1}
```

would translate to

```
\global\def\myothermacro{test1}
```

which is equivalent to

```
\gdef\myothermacro{test1}
```

Note that some commands "transcend" groups. See, for example, [Why do `\setcounter` and `\addtocounter` commands have global effect, while `\setlength` and `\addtolength` commands obey the normal scoping rules?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25462/5764)